# Rails Bootstrap Form: Fill the whole horizontal row?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

This code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <%= bootstrap_form_for @keen, remote: true, html: {class: 'emailForm form-inline'} do |f| %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, hide_label: true %>
            <%= f.submit "OK, LET'S GO!" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

places the `input field` and `submit button` on the same horizontal row (that's good), but both the `input field` and `submit button` is "forced" to the left of the row. How can I make it so the input field and submit button is filling the whole row (where the input field takes up most of the space)?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but I believe all you need to do is this:

change

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
```

to

```
<div class="col-md-12">
```

`col-md-8` is telling the element to take up 8 of the 12 available columns, and `col-md-offset-2` is telling that column to move (offset) 2 columns to the right.

Comment: Sorry, that will only make the row fill the whole container from left to right, but the input field and submit button will still be forced to the left on the row and not fill the row 100%..